# "Finish OF" or "Finish TO" difference

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

Macmillan dictionary examples:

1. A swim in the sea seemed a perfect finish to the day.
2. I didn't see the finish of the game

Apart from these I have also heard:
**Greatest ever finish to a cricket match **.

Tell me the difference between "Finish of" and "finish to".

Answer (score 2):

finish to the day, **to the day** is a prepositional phrase.

finish to the game, to day, to the show, and other nouns.

finish of the game, **the end of the game**

Many activities can have an end or finish.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little hard to explain, but I'm going to try my best.

A finish of something is like an event that was happening and then it ended on its own, like the finish/end of a movie, you can't control it. It happens naturally.

Now if you put a finish/end to something you do it yourself or something does it and ends it immediately.